# How do I get a search button on dock applications?

Tags: dock

I've used Docky and GLX-Dock (because i want a dock on the bottom, not the side) but I can't figure out how to add the search button to either of them. I'd like either suggestions for dock apps that will enable bottom docks as well as the search app on the bottom of the dock.

Comment: and what will this search app search? the internet, the computer files, recent files, installed apps, online apps...

Comment: When you first install  ubuntu, there is a search button on the top right corner to search for apps and stuff. That's the one I'm talking bout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any with such a search feature.

As a workaround, you can install cairo dock `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock`. Launch it, right click on it and choose "Cairo Dock"->"Configure", then activate the following plugins:

- Under "Desktop", activate "Applications menu": This will enable you to launch any installed app in your computer.
- Under "Accessories", activate "Recent Events": This will enable you to open/launch any recent files be it documents, music, folders, etc.
- Under "Files", activate "Folders": You can have your favorite folders in there for a quick access.

Hope I've helped.